# Getopt generates a double-dash (--) even if there's none on the command line, and doesn't validate an extraneous argument

Tags: bash, getopt

I'm learning the `getopt` command and using the following diagnostic script to study its workings:

```
$ cat test-getopt.sh
#!/bin/bash
args=`getopt ab:c $*`
set -- $args
for i
do
    echo "-->$i"
done
echo $#
```

I cannot understand its behavour in the following cases. Could you clarify?

- 1st case:

  ```
  $ ./test-getopt.sh  -ab  arg -c
  -->-a
  -->-b
  -->arg
  -->-c
  -->--
  5
  ```

  Why does `getopt` add `--` as `$5`? What does it mean here? To point out the end of options?
- 2nd case:

  ```
  $ ./test-getopt.sh  -ab  arg  c
  -->-a
  -- -b
  -->arg
  -->--
  -->c
  5
  ```

  Now, `getopt` adds `c` as `$5`'s value, after that `--`. It is not a option, what does `c` mean here?

  - Which kind of element is it -- option, or option's argument, or positional argument?
  - It's not defined in `getopt`'s parameter specifying valid options, why doesn't the program raise an error?

I've already skimmed through the [`getopt` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt) as well as [some](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial) [tutorials](https://gist.github.com/cosimo/3760587) but couldn't quite work out a clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [`getopt` manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getopt):

> Normally, no non-option parameters output is generated until all
>   options and their arguments have been generated. Then '--' is
>   generated as a single parameter, and after it the non-option
>   parameters in the order they were found, each as a separate parameter.

I.e. `--` by itself is generated to signify the end of options. (And after it, positional parameters are generated if there are any.)

I guess this is done for uniformity -- to use the same code logic regardless of whether the user specified `--` on the command line or not.

---

In the 2nd case, `c` is a positional argument. Positional arguments are not checked by `getopt` in any way and are rather passed as-is. The manpage doesn't say anything about validating non-option arguments:

> *getopt* is used to break up (parse) options in command lines for easy
>   parsing by shell procedures, and to check for legal options.

---

Finally, note that to correctly process arguments with whitespace, you need to: use `$@` instead of `$*`; quoting; `eval` with `set`; and use the enhanced mode of `getopt` -- as per [Example of how to parse options with bash/getopt](https://gist.github.com/cosimo/3760587). Also should use `bash` `-e` mode to quit the program on an invalid option:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
args=`getopt -o ab:c -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$args"
for i
do
  echo "-->$i"
done
echo $#

$ ./test-getopt.sh -b "arg ument"
-->-b
-->arg ument
-->--
3

$ ./test-getopt.sh -d ; echo $?
getopt: unknown option -- d
1
```

Also, a `while` loop with `shift` as per the same example could be more convenient that `for` as it: makes it easy to get the next argument -- to get the option's argument and check if there is an argument if it's optional; check the number of the remaining (positional) arguments when you're done with options.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use constructs like this to run getopts:

```
# Set defaults
opt_a=0; opt_b=""; opt_c=false

# Step through options
while getopts ab:c opt; do
        case "$opt" in
                a) opt_a=1 ;;
                b) opt_b="${OPTARG:?The -b option requires an argument.}" ;;
                c) opt_c=true ;;
                *) usage; exit 64 ;;
        esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))
```

Use of `shift` like this at the end causes your positional arguments to be shifted back such that the first argument that `getopts` **can't** process becomes `$1`. For example, if the above snippet was part of a script named `foo`, one might run:

```
$ foo -ab meh smoo blarg
```

which would set `$opt_a` to `1`, `$opt_b` to `"meh"`, `$1` to `"smoo"` and `$2` to `"blarg"` for the portion of the script following the snippet.

Comment: Note that you're talking about `getopts` (a Bash builtin) rather than `getopt` (an external program).